# Why use a VDI in virtualbox if the size will never decrease back to its actual usage?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine

I just recently found out that the size of a dynamic disk in VirtualBox will increase with every write action that takes place, and will never decrease. Especially, it will not decrease if files on the disk are deleted.

I wonder what reason there is to use such a construct. Eventually, the size will max out anyway. Why not just use a fixed size from the start?

Also, it seems that my maximum capazity of my dynamic disk is just the maximum capazity of my hosts SSD. Maybe because I imported this disk from another VM.

This means additional trouble since now my dynamic drive in the guest can max out my hosts drive size.

Comment: The typical way to shrink an disk image is to copy all used blocks to a new file and then delete the old one. As far as I know Virtualbox has no other integrated way to shrinking a existing disk image "in-place".

Comment: Using modern TRIM features in the guest OS would allow to implement a very simple way to reduce the disk size assuming the underlaying file-system supports sparse files (NTFS does some file-system on Linux does support it, too): sparse files can have "holes" - where not every data block really exists on disk). When the guest sends the TRIMed blocks the VM could directly translate them to sparse blocks so their disk space will be available again. Not sure why this have not been implemented yet.

Comment: Well, this makes this answer even more unfitting.   <-- You may think so, by Hyper-V and VBOX on a workstation are not even worth free compared to VMware which is licensed but so much more vastly friendly and easier.